# Edit drop--down list when modifying in codeigniter

Tags: java, php, codeigniter

help! I have two drop-down lists in which the comunas drop-down list is ciudades dependent, it works perfect. The problem comes when I need to bring the drop-down lists with the saved data to modify them. It will only get me to bring what is selected in the list of ciudades, but in the comunas it will not be able to achieve it.

Is there any way to do this? I have become somewhat confused.

This is my code!

```
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->
THIS IS THE VIEW CODE

 <label>Ciudad:</label><select id="idciudad" name="idciudad" required autocomplete="off">
                <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
                <?php foreach($listaciudades as $ciudad):?>

        <option value="<?= $ciudad['idciudad']?>"
            <?php if ($idciudad == $ciudad['idciudad']) : ?> selected<?php endif; ?>
        >
            <?= $ciudad['nombre']?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

           <label>Comuna:</label> <select id="idcomuna" name="idcomuna">
                <option value="0">Comuna</option>
            </select>




        <script type="text/javascript">   
            $(document).ready(function() {                       
                $("#idciudad").change(function() {
                    $("#idciudad option:selected").each(function() {
                        idciudad = $('#idciudad').val();
                        $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/clientes/fillCiudades", {
                            idciudad : idciudad
                        }, function(data) {
                            $("#idcomuna").html(data);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

THIS IS THE CONTROLLER CODE

```
 public function fillCiudades() {
    $idciudad = $this->input->post('idciudad');

    if($idciudad){
        $this->load->model('ClientesModel');
        $comuna = $this->ClientesModel->getCiudades($idciudad);
        echo '<option value="0">Comunas</option>';
        foreach($comuna as $fila){
            echo '<option value="'. $fila->idcomuna .'">'. $fila->nombre .'</option>';
        }
    }  else {
        echo '<option value="0">Comunas</option>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to parse a variable with the saved idcomuna from the controller to the view, as you do with the saved idciudad. To do that, you must edit the code of the function that loads the view (you didn't include it on your question).

It would be something like (**this code is for guidance only**):

```
public function thefunctionthatloadstheview($idcliente) {
    // The rest of your code here...

    // I supposed you get the client data from database using a model, something like this...
    $this->load->model('ClientesModel');
    $cliente = $this->ClientesModel->getCliente($idcliente);

    $your_view_data = array(
        'idciudad' => $cliente->idciudad,
        'idcomuna' => $cliente->idcomuna,
        // The rest of the data like $listaciudades, etc...
    );

    $this->load->view('your_view', $your_view_data);
}
```

Once you have parsed the *$idcomuna* as you did with *$idciudad*, you must make two other changes in your view and the *fillCiudades* function.

The items of the second dropdown only load when the first one changes. To make it load when the page does, modify the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Create a function to make POST request, parsing the value of the first dropdown (ciudades) and the saved value of idcomuna...
    function fillCiudades_js() {
        $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/clientes/fillCiudades", {
            idciudad: $('#idciudad').val(),
            idcomuna: <?php echo $idcomuna; ?>
        }, function(data) {
            $("#idcomuna").html(data);
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Make a request when the page is ready...
        fillCiudades_js();

        // Make a request while the first dropdown changes...
        $("#idciudad").on("change", fillCiudades_js());
    });
</script>
```

Then, modify the *fillCiudades* function to get the value of *idcomuna* parsed through the Javascript code:

```
public function fillCiudades() {
    $idciudad = $this->input->post('idciudad');
    $idcomuna = $this->input->post('idcomuna');

    if ($idciudad) {
        $this->load->model('ClientesModel');
        $comuna = $this->ClientesModel->getCiudades($idciudad);
        echo '<option value="0">Comunas</option>';
        foreach ($comuna as $fila) {
            echo '<option value="'. $fila->idcomuna .'"' . ($idcomuna == $fila->idcomuna ? 'selected' : '') . '>'. $fila->nombre .'</option>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option value="0">Comunas</option>';
    }
}
```

With those changes, the second dropdown should be loaded with the saved value selected by default.

P.S. I couldn't test the code, so it's possible that there is some small error... but I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks friend, I probe it but now I don't even see values ​​in the drop-down list of comunas. Anyway thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I found a bug in the Javascript code, I'm gonna edit it to make it work correctly.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate it !

Comment: Dear, thank you very much it works perfectly when pressing "modify" button, but I have a new problem that now does not let me add new records, when selecting "ciudades" I do not load the list of "comunas" but to modify my sample the data in a perfect way.

Comment: Probably $idcomuna is only declared while you try to edit a record, but it's not declared while you try to create it. Check the code of the function you code to create records and ensure the $idcomuna is declared there too. If not, just declare it and assign an empty value like 0.